# abstract file handling library for Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there a Haskell library for handling files and traversing directories that represents files not by `String`s (which are relative paths) but actual file objects?  You'd think that `ls -lR` could be done like this:

```
walk f = do
  d <- doesDirectoryExist f
  case d of
    False -> putStrLn $ unwords [ "file", f ]
    True ->  listDirectory f >>= mapM_ walk
```

using http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.2.5.1/docs/System-Directory.html but actually it cannot - I have to manually splice files' names together. I know how this works, but it's definitely ugly.

For reference, Java gets this somewhat more right, because they have `Path`? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

```
DirectoryStream<Path> s = Files.newDirectoryStream(p);
for (Path f : s) { System.out.println (f); }
```

Comment: This may be useful to you: http://chrisdone.com/posts/path-package

Comment: this too: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/path-io-1.0.1/docs/Path-IO.html (is able to represent relative and absolute paths as _different types_ – super useful for scripting in Haskell – and there's an operator `</>` for gluing directories and filenames together)

Comment: Thanks. path-io looks right, and I am now using it. Though  it is inconvenient that I have to go via System.FilePath for getting basename, dirname, extension.